# c++ program to digits of a number

Tags: c++, linux

I'm a beginner at c++ and this part of the assignment is throwing me off. How could I get the function find the amount of digits in a number

Comment: `result  = num / 10;` change this to `num  = num / 10;`. Also remove the line `index=1;`

Comment: When `index` is zero, do you expect to get the leftmost digit or the rightmost digit?

Comment: It is better to work around such class assignments by self. Otherwise you will never learn programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

```
int getDigit(int num, int index) // return the index'th digit of num
{
int result;
for(int i=0; i < index; i++)
{
        num = num / 10;
}
result = num % 10;
return result;
}
```